# Loading screen wrong resolution

Tags: 11.10, ati, graphics, plymouth, thinkpad

I've got a problem when booting:

I see the GRUB screen where I can choose what exactly to boot into - after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> my screen simply shows me that purplish background and after some seconds it shows me the Ubuntu logo with the logo dots in a pretty low resolution (my guess would be 640x480); it then loads quickly and takes me to the login screen. So it's working, just not quite right I guess.

My computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad x121e, with a AMD e350 CPU and an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6310 graphics card (fully detected and working with the `vesa:wrestler` drivers).

Answer (score 2):

initially, you can verify what are the resolutions that can be used by your video card in GRUB... To do this, restart your computer and, in the GRUB menu screen, type the 'c' key. The GRUB prompt will be shown.

In the GRUB prompt you should type the command 'vbeinfo' and hit Enter. GRUB will show the supported resolutions that can be used by it with your video card. After taking a look (and, if you want, writting them in a paper) you can hit 'Esc' and start Ubuntu.

In Ubuntu, I suggest that you check the file `/etc/default/grub` and, if you want, you can change the parameter `GRUB_GFXMODE` (the default value is 640x480). Note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE (i.e., the supported resolutions that you looked previously).

If you change the parameter, you should run the `update-grub` command:

`sudo update-grub`

I hope this can help you.

Regards,

Rafael.