# 17.10 Wrong resolution in grub & boot loading screen & login screen

Tags: boot, grub2, display-resolution, 17.10, gdm

Newly installed Ubuntu 17.10.

Monitor: 2560x1080 60hz resolution with HDMI cable.

At boot loading I had some weird glitches as described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975094/how-to-disable-wayland-in-17-10-in-gdm3-login-screen/975188) .

I disabled wayland in boot loading screen using:
    WaylandEnable=false

The boot loading screen & the login screen have the wrong resolution.

[image]

After I log in the resolution changes to the correct one.

How can I change the resolution during the boot loading screen and the login screen?

I already [tried to edit](https://askubuntu.com/a/70066/758460) `/etc/default/grub` and add my resolution for `GRUB_GFXMODE`. But it has no effect. Also related to this, when I type `vbeinfo` in the grub command line it says command not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combinding some answers and comments primarily from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/54067/723193) and most of the following answer is from [artfulrobot's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/747439/723193)

1) Turn on

2) At the grub menu press <kbd>c</kbd> to get the grub command line

3) Type `videoinfo`
  This lists all the modes - it is the <width>x<height> you need to make note of. Only modes listed here will work and may not include your desired resolution.

4) Optionally, there is a `videotest` command which you can use to test a given resolution, e.g. `videotest 1280x1024`.  **However**, while this test worked for me, I could not then get back to the grub menu!  So that's not quite as useful (unless anyone can explain how to escape the test.)

5) Run the `normal` command to return to the normal grub menu.

6) Boot up fully and in a terminal run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. So un-comment and set the following lines to your desired mode. You may also need to add nomodeset.

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD="keep"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

6) Run `update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: My native resolution is not present in the videoinfo list and it does not work when set in GRUB_GFXMODE. When I set nomodeset all other resolution are no longer available in the system settings. I ended up putting in a lower resolution for GRUB_GFXMODE, the resolution automatically adjusts to the native one, and set GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD="keep"

Comment: Yes the resolutions listed by 'videoinfo' are the only ones supported by grub on a given set of hardware.

Comment: This only works for the first 1-2 restarts then it reverts back to the previous behavior. If I run update-grub it fixes it temporarily until the next day.